# Profile Java application in virtual machine environment (eg vbox, vpc, vmware etc)

Tags: java, profiling, virtualization, vmware, jprofiler

For last two days I am trying to profile a  java application on a VM environment (dont confuse this VM with JVM). We have amazon ec2 instances running. Those are infact running vmware images. We use licensed version of Jprofiler6 to profile java application.

Now the situation is, I want to profile a java app under a virtual environment. When I run jprofiler in the VM it askes to select JVM from a list. But unfortunately I dont see any JVM is listed.

When I do the same in my own physical machine, I see JVMs are listed. So I can profile it on my physical machine but not in ec2 instances.

Do you got any idea how can I profile under virtual environment?

Comment: What does JProfiler support suggest?

Comment: There is no difference debugging/profiling a remote machine and doing so w/ VM. Connect to the remote process and profile.

Comment: Oops! I didnt check support while posting. Just checked it. It seems we need to purchase support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VM instance is a separate computer, accessible via the normal network. You will need to set up the JVM in the guest to enable remote debugging/profiling, then specify on jprofiler startup the remote host.